# Get filesystem type with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a project in node js and I need to get the file system type of a disk i.e., I want to know if it's FAT or NTFS etc...
Is there any way I can accomplish this with node js? Any help is appreciated . Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you didn't specify target machine's operating system, you can use such command under Windows:

```
fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo <disk letter here>:
```

to show output simillar to this one:

```
H:\>fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo c:

Volume Name :
Volume Serial Number : 0x4c31bcb3
Max Component Length : 255
File System Name : NTFS
Supports Case-sensitive filenames
Preserves Case of filenames
Supports Unicode in filenames
Preserves & Enforces ACL's
Supports file-based Compression
Supports Disk Quotas
Supports Sparse files
Supports Reparse Points
Supports Object Identifiers
Supports Encrypted File System
Supports Named Streams
```

You need only to parse command output correctly. I would recommend you storing filesystem names in array and seeking for every in command output excluding first line. This way you can be sure which filesystem is used by target machine.

Here you have code to print what does this command output to your commandline:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo c:', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    // node couldn't execute the command
    return;
  }

  // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

This is untested code, I really think that you want to write own snippet. I can't decide will this code work because I have no opportunity now.

Also, why would you check filesystem used?

Comment: So, there is no other way to get the filesystem type other than this? Because I need this code to run on window , Mac and Linux. Btw this is for a cross platform disk encryption tool using electron framework.

Comment: You can check out is there a way to do it on linux - ill leave it for you, but when it's about non-trivial disk access - there is no multiplatform way. If you want such tool - I think you should use other language.

Comment: Also, you can use some native lang like C to write tool to get filesystem under linux mac and windows and in your js code you should just detect operating system and run valid executable supplied with your program.

Comment: One reason the check which fs is used is because different `stat` fields are supported/meaningful on different fs's on the same os. On Windows `ctime` is meaningful for NTFS but garbage. On Linux `birthtime` is only supported on several newer fs's.

Answer (score -1):

you can use github.com/resin-io-modules/drivelist

then

```
const drivelist = require('drivelist');



drivelist.list((error, drives) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }

  console.log(drives);
});
```

Comment: then -> could work - - var exec = require("child_process").spawn
var cmd = 'wmic logicaldisk get name, FileSystem';
const list  = spawn(cmd);

Comment: I've just posted such answer